# Alternative to IF Statement for deletion

Tags: sql, if-statement, ssis, sql-delete

I have the following script running in a SSIS Execute SQL Task which is taking exceptionally long to execute :

```
DECLARE @Year int
DECLARE @Month int

SET @Year = YEAR(GETDATE())
SET @Month = MONTH(GETDATE())

IF @Month IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
 BEGIN

  SET @Year = @Year-1

  DELETE FROM GLYTDMovement 
  WHERE CGYear >= @Year
   AND Entity NOT LIKE 'TT%'

 END
ELSE
 BEGIN

  SET @Year = @Year

  DELETE FROM GLYTDMovement 
  WHERE CGYear >= @Year
   AND Entity NOT LIKE 'TT%'

 END
```

Any advise on how to adjust to improve performance?

Comment: I doubt there is much that you can change in this code to make it faster. It's possible you've got record locking issues if you're deleting from a live system, or perhaps there are some triggers which are fired on the deletions which are worth looking at. It might also be worth looking at the indexing on the table. Is CGYear indexed? I'm never that great at indexes, but I think you'd ideally want it DESC and with "includes (Entity)". Happy to be corrected on that.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the following:

```
DECLARE @Year int
DECLARE @Month int

SET @Year = YEAR(GETDATE())
SET @Month = MONTH(GETDATE())

DELETE FROM GLYTDMovement 
WHERE Entity NOT LIKE 'TT%'
  AND ((CGYear >= @Year-1 AND @Month <= 9) OR (CGYear >= @Year AND @Month >= 10))
```

Furthermore it might be worth a try to evaluate the current dates year and month outside of this statement and then use an expression in the delete, which will look something like this:

```
...AND ((CGYear >= 2021-1 AND 3 <= 9) OR (CGYear >= 2021 AND 3 >= 10))
```

SQL Server / SSIS tend to be less performant when dealing with variables in the WHERE condition.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is executing exactly one `DELETE` statement.  There is little that you can do to speed that up -- no loops, joins, or anything else that comes to mind.

What are possible issues?

- The table may be really, really big and the `WHERE` clause requires full table scans.
- Lots and lots of rows may be being deleted.
- Resource contention and locks.

There is little that you can do about the second two.  The first is tricky but you might find that a simple index on `(Entity, CGYear)` speeds the queries.

For a more focused index, you can create a filtered index:

```
create index fidx_GLYTDMovement_year on GLYTDMovement(year)
    where Entity >= 'TT' and Entity < 'TU';
```

This is equivalent to your logic (assuming a reasonable collation) but filtered indexes do not support `LIKE`.

Then be sure to use the same `WHERE` clause in the query:

```
WHERE CGYear >= @Year AND
      Entity >= 'TT' and Entity < 'TU'
```